# How to updated OS X theme so it looks like iOS 7 design

Tags: macos

I saw few people have fancy OS X design that resemble iOS 7 design. I did not find any official information about it on Apple site about Mavericks. Though this theme appears at new Xcode page. I updated OS X but I did not get this design .. and I did not find a way to apply this design via Systems Preferences.

So how would I change my Maverics design?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is [OS X Yosemite](https://www.apple.com/osx/preview/), the next version of OS X.

Comment: is it possible to install it already? I saw guy was using it. Probably there are some alpha versions...

Comment: @putinhuylo  go to https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/